# make:entity command isn't registered in my Symfony 4 project

Tags: symfony, console, doctrine, symfony4

After performing the command:

```
composer require doctrine maker
```

I tried to create the database using the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

and tried creating new entity using the command:

```
php bin/console make:entity Product
```

but I just get the message:

> [error] Error thrown while running command ""make:entity" Product". Message: "There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace."

Comment: Did you get any errors during the require?  Are you using php 7.1.3+?  I just did a fresh install and the make commands are there as expected.

Comment: php version: 7.0.10, i didn't get any errors during the require

Comment: According to the composer.json you need at least 7.1.3.  The maker bundle itself only needs 7.0.0 but the skeleton needs 7.1.3.  https://github.com/symfony/skeleton/blob/4.0/composer.json  Bit strange but I expect you might need to upgrade your php to get this to work.  The framework bundle also seems to need 7.1.3.

Comment: I'll upgrade my PHP and do it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed PHP v7.2.1

Required the Maker package again

And then the console commands worked well.

The problem seemed to be caused because Composer.json requires PHP 7.1.3.

and actually Symfony 4 requires PHP 7.1