# Command "make:entity" is not defined. Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.4

when I run
php bin/console make:entity
the output is

```
[critical] Error thrown while running command ""make:entity"". Message: "Command "make:entity" is not defined.
```

Did you mean one of these?
make:admin:crud
make:admin:dashboard
make:admin:migration"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make:entity command isn't registered in my Symfony 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117675/makeentity-command-isnt-registered-in-my-symfony-4-project)

Comment: my php version is 7.4.16

Comment: it seems like necessary symfony package is not installed, check this documentation https://symfony.com/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/current/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your APP_ENV is set to dev;
generally, this only works in dev mode depending on your configuration with composer